# Retrieve values in html table based on combo selected in same jsp

Tags: jquery, html, sql, jsp

first my combo box is:

```
 <select name="months">
  <option value="JUL">JULY</option>
  <option value="AUG">AUGUST</option>
  <option value="SEP">SEPTEMBER</option>

</select>
```

based on the value selected here i need value for the string "selected" so that i can retrieve values from data base using this string

```
    <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Emp id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Rating</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
  </tr>
  <%



Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
int id = 0;
String selected= "null";
....................

</table>
```

Comment: Create an Ajax call, using jquery and send it to a Servlet, where you can call a service to do the data retrieval and pass it back to jQuery to display it.

Comment: can u help me with outline? please